# Translate PSTricks to Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

For my thesis I am using [DIA](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.de) for drawing little graphs or images.

After this I use the export function which create a .tex file with PSTricks syntax inside.

Compiling this in my maindocument seems to work, however I have difficulties to 'read' the imagefile an maintain little parts of the image afterwards like including references, as I am just familiar with Tikz.

Is there some sort of resource which can convert/translate the PSTricks syntax to Tikz?

Comment: You might want to look into how the package [circuit macros](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuit-macros?lang=en) is handling this. Probably you don't need the m4 layer in between.

Comment: There is no converter! It has to be done by hand ...